# Adding padded number as QString to QByteArray produces unwanted character

Tags: arrays, string, qt, null-terminated, zero-padding

I have a `QByteArray` which contains the telegram in a special format that is then sent via UDP to a remote machine for further processing. I use `QByteArray::append()` to put the telegram together.

One of the components of the telegram is an index: 1, 2, 3, ..., 999. This index needs to be padded with zeroes in the front: 001, 002, 003, ..., 999. In order to do that I initially hard coded the index for testing purposes:

```
...
telegram.append("001");
...
```

but later I obviously had to move to a more general solution like

```
...
QString paddedIdx = QString("%1").arg(idx, 2, QChar('0'));
telegram.append(paddedIdx);
...
```

The initial try worked without any issues. Looking in the debugged contents of the `telegram` I was able to see that "002" is appended to the byte array. However with the new solution I get "0\002" and as a result the processing of the telegram on the remote machine fails (I use reg ex for the parsing). If I'm not mistaken the `\0` is the terminating character however it's definitely something I'm not expecting to see in my byte array.

Comment: I would go simpler and use "QString::prepend" instead of argument implementation. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#prepend

Comment: `"0\002"` is not `{'0', NULL, '0', '2'}` it is `{'0', 2}`. This is because `\002` is the octal number `002`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:
QString paddedIdx = QString("%1").arg(QString::number(idx), 3, QChar('0'));

Comment: Indeed, the conversion of the number to a string before padding did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your problem is that your call of `arg()` is missing the base parameter. So instead of calling

```
QString::arg(int a, int fieldWidth, int base, const QChar& fillChar)
```

the compiler selects a matching overload, does an implicit cast to an (unprintable) char and calls

```
QString::arg(QChar a, int fieldWidth, const QChar& fillChar)
```

To fix this you either add the missing parameter (and use the expected `fieldWidth` of 3 instead of 2 as in your example)

```
QString paddedIdx(QString("%1").arg(idx, 3, 10, QChar('0')));
```

or use the more verbose construct

```
QString paddedIdx(QString::number(idx).rightJustified(3, QChar('0')));
```

BTW, it's rather easy to detect this behaviour using a debugger and stepping through the code. It would also be faster than writing up a SO question. Recommended reading: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/